# Django - How can I filter and count related objects of different ids

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Model 1:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    names = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey('School', on_delete=CASCADE, null=True, 
    blank=True)
```

Model 2:

```
class School(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

I want to count the total students who are in different schools.

I tried `total_student = Members.filter(school=1+5+8).count()`but this is not working. Note: 1, 5 and 8 are the ids of the same type of schools in the school model which different members attend.

Please help me get this right.

Comment: you mean {"school_name" : count } like this?
if you want total students from all the schools all you have to do is Member count without any filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [__in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) query filter of Django for filtering on multiple data per column:

```
total_student = Members.filter(student__in=[1,5,8]).count()
```

Comment: Although the name of the foreign key field is weird (student) the proper filter is `student_id__in=(1, 5, 8)`

Comment: @Benoît thank you for the correction, I changed the field name to student. There no different as the format of the list or tuple because in the document __in accepts multiple types `In a given iterable; often a list, tuple, or queryset`.  Also don't have to specify _id because the default field for foreign key is the id

Comment: @LinhNguyen thank you so much. Appreciate your great help. It worked well.